# Django search / filter across multiple models

Tags: python, django, web, search, filter

In my Django website, I'm trying to create a search bar on my homepage that returns results that are stored in two different models(Articles, Jobs)

Currently, I get an empty result set when I search using this code:

In models.py,

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    objects = None

    news_title = models.CharField(db_column="title", max_length=400)
    news_url = models.URLField(db_column="link", max_length=400)
    image_link = models.CharField(db_column="image", max_length=400)
    published_date = models.CharField(db_column="published_date", max_length=400)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "articles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_title


class Jobs(models.Model):
    objects = None

    company = models.CharField(db_column='company', max_length=100)
    job_title = models.CharField(db_column='job_title', max_length=300)
    experience = models.CharField(db_column='experience', max_length=300)
    edu_level = models.CharField(db_column='edu_level', max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "job_list"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

In views.py,

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', '')

        articles_results = Articles.objects.filter(Q(news_title__icontains=query))
        jobs_results = Jobs.objects.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=query))

        context={
            'articles':articles_results,
            'jobs':jobs_results,
        }

        return render(request, 'blog/search_results.html', context)
```

In main_view.html, I'm using this code for creating a search bar:

```
<form action="{%url 'search_results' %}" method="get" values="{{request.GET.q}}" class="search-jobs-form">
    <div class="row mb-5">
         <input name="q" type="text" values="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And in search_results.html,

```
{% block content %}
    {% for job in jobs %}
        <h5>{{job.job_title}}</h5>
        <p>{{job.company}}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for article in articles %}
        <h5>{{article.news_title}}</h5>
        <p>{{article.published_date}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the default manager (`objects`) to `None`?

Comment: I didn’t set a manager for this model.. Do I need a manager in this case? In other pages of our website, where I didn’t use the filter function, I was still able to call the object...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "call the object" but you must have a manager to use most ORM functions. Django provides a default manager called `objects` for you. Why are you setting it to `None` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using class SearchView(ListView) in views.py and made it work

Here's the code that I used

```
#index.html Search Bar
<form method="get" class="search-jobs-form" action="{% url 'main_search'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Job title, Company..." name="search_query">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-white btn-search">Search Job</button>
</form>
```

In views,

```
#views.py
def main_search(request):
    q = request.GET['search_query']

    articles = Articles.objects.filter(news_title__icontains=q)
    jobs = Jobs.objects.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=q) | Q(company__icontains=q))
    return render(request, "blog/main_search.html", {'articles':articles, 'jobs':jobs, 'page_name':'Search Results', 'q':q})
```